# libsoxr in Windows x64 platform with inline asm is not compiling

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am trying to compile `libsoxr` (it is derived from `libsox` library by Audacity team) library. I can compile osx 32, osx 64 and win32. They use inline asm and Windows x64 platform doesn't support inline asm. Problematic code piece is this:

```
#if HAVE_FENV_H
  #include <fenv.h>
#elif defined _MSC_VER
  #define FE_INVALID    1
  #define FE_DIVBYZERO  4
  #define FE_OVERFLOW   8
  #define FE_UNDERFLOW  16
  #define FE_INEXACT    32
  #define FE_ALL_EXCEPT (FE_INEXACT|FE_DIVBYZERO|FE_UNDERFLOW|FE_OVERFLOW|FE_INVALID)
  static __inline int fetestexcept(int excepts)
  {
    short status_word;
    __asm fnstsw status_word
    return status_word & excepts & FE_ALL_EXCEPT;
  }

  static __inline int feclearexcept(int excepts)
  {
    int16_t status[14];
    __asm fnstenv status
    status[2] &= ~(excepts & FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    __asm fldenv status
    return 0;
  }
#endif
```

I don't know what `fnstenv` and `fldenv` do. May somebody guide me for making compatible with x64?

Comment: These instructions are working on the x87 state. Windows x64 isn't normally using the x87 floating point, but the SSE floating point instructions.

Comment: I am using Visual C++ express edition 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are compiling with the Microsoft compiler then you can use RTL functions instead of inline assembly.

To test for particular floating point status flags call [`_statusfp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9st43tcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To clear floating point status flags call [`_clearfp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49bs2z07.aspx).

In order to use `_statusfp` you'll need to translate from the raw 8087 flags, to the abstract flags used by `_statusfp`.

**Update**

The code in the question is an implementation of a small part of `fenv.h` which is part of C99. It's needed for the MS compiler since it only implements C89. In my view you would be much better off using a real C99 compiler. That would come with an implementation of `fenv.h`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked `fnstenv` and it takes 28 bytes info but `_statusfp` returned just an `int` (4 btes). In the code they use just second 16bit with bitwise operation. Do you think I need to try _statusfp2? because it takes unsigned int pointer. I can't find an info about how many bytes does it take.

Comment: Hmm, `feclearexcept` allows you to clear selected exceptions, but `_clearfp` clears all exceptions. I'm not sure the MSVC RTL supports clearing only some exceptions. But it would be odd to only clear some. I bet all calls to `feclearexcept` clear them all.

Comment: Now I see what is it. I can try `_clearfp` and looked the results. Maybe they clear just second 16bit because of performance. What do you think about `fnstsw`? Is it a function that I can use for the same job?

Comment: `fnstsw` matches up to `_statusfp`. But you need to take care to make sure that the `FE_XXX` macros are mapped properly.

Comment: Thanks, I could compile 64bit version with MinGW64 compiler :)

Answer (score 2):

These two functions are part of the C standard so I doubt this is the first time someone has wanted them for MSVC—have a look around to see what other projects have done.  If nothing turns up and you want a quick and easy solution, you should be able to further qualify the

#elif defined _MSC_VER

directive that wraps this code for your compiler (_M_X64) to not use these inline assembly versions—default (slower) code should come into effect.

Comment: The two functions in the question are part of the C standard? Really? Where in the standard?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the page number! A quick google reveals http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fetestexcept.html which has the following reference: ISO/IEC 9899:1999   AFAIK, these functions are also in newer (2011) versions of both the C & C++ standards.

Comment: @Rob Thank you. Actually I don't have to use MS compiler. I can use gcc too. It is a dll project. I don't have gcc experience on Windows. I have downloaded MinGW64 compilers. There is a problem with cmake and MinGW64. Have you ever use fenv.h with 64bit Windows with gcc?

Comment: @Rob Ah, I'm getting there now! The code in the Q is an implementation of `fenv.h` for MSVC which is not a C99 compiler. +1